# Concatenate Excel files, use filename as an index throwing an error

Tags: python, pandas

I have around 20 XLSX files ranging from 4-10 mb.

I want to grab a certain sheet in those xlsx files and concat them into one file.

Each xlsx file is named in a sequential week order, and the sheet I am trying to parse has no date, so I'm using the file_name as the the index and will reverse engineer a week date.

I am using the following code, which I use quite often to concat multiple files into one df. I am also using basename to add in the name but get the following error.

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 461 elements, new values have 457 elements


import pandas as pd
from os.path import basename
import os
import glob
path = os.getcwd()
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")

    frame = pd.DataFrame()
    master_list = []

for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_,sheet_name = "Base data",index_col=None, 
    header=0)
    df.index = [os.path.basename(f)] * len(data)
    master_list.append(df)

    frame = pd.concat(master_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for list of DataFrames and then create list of filenames used for parameter `keys` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name="Base data",index_col=None,header=0) for f in allFiles]

keys = [os.path.basename(f) for f in allFiles]
frame = pd.concat(dfs, keys=keys)
#if want remove default index values
#frame = pd.concat(dfs, keys=keys).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Comment: Perfecto! took a while to run on my machine (6gig i3 monstrosity until I pass probation)! but this gave me exactly what I needed. the 2nd argument in the pd.concat are the keys the index?

Comment: @Datanovice - exactly, it create MultiIndex - first levele are filenames and second levels are RangeIndexes of each small DataFrame.